# Python - Remove all keys from dictionary if key is less than number and over certain percentage

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently can remove all keys that are below 3.0 by using:

```
tempratings={'Shane': {'127 Hours': 4.5, 'The Revenant': 4.8, 'Panic Room 4.8': 3.7, 'The Spotlight': 3.6, 'Panic Room': 4.8, 'How I Live Now': 4.6, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 5.0, 'The Martian': 4.8, 'The Hunger Games': 4.5, 'Interstellar': 4.5, 'Dead Poets Society': 5.0, 'The Finest Hours': 4.7, 'Get Hard': 2.0}, 'Aaron': {'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.0, 'Pacific Rim': 3.0, 'John Wick': 4.0, 'The Blair Witch Project': 5.0, 'Scott Pilgrim Vs The World': 4.0, 'A Talking Cat': 5.0, 'Space Jam': 5.0}, 'Eli': {'The Guardians Of The Galaxy': 3.5, 'The Breakfast Club': 5.0, 'Back To The Future': 4.0, 'E.T.': 5.0, 'Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome': 3.0, 'Mr. Smith Goes To Washington': 4.7, 'Meet Joe Black': 5.0, 'Jurassic Park': 4.0, 'Pulp Fiction': 4.0, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 5.0, 'The Martian': 4.5, 'Die Hard': 4.0, 'The Dark Knight': 5.0, 'Dead Poets Society': 5.0, 'The Shining': 3.5, 'Inception': 5.0, 'Mad Max': 4.0, '127 Hours': 3.0, 'Rocky': 5.0, 'Blade Runner': 3.5, 'The Wizard Of Oz': 5.0, 'Interstellar': 5.0, 'The Sixth Sense': 3.5, 'Gladiator': 5.0, 'The Lion King': 5.0, 'Toy Story 3': 3.5, 'Good Will Hunting': 5.0, 'The Revenant': 4.5, 'The Matrix': 5.0, 'Full Metal Jacket': 4.5, 'Inglourious Basterds': 5.0, 'Forrest Gump': 5.0, 'Saving Private Ryan': 5.0, 'John Wick': 3.5, 'Up': 3.0, 'Titanic': 5.0, 'Avatar': 5.0, 'Jurassic World': 3.5, 'The Silence Of The Lambs': 4.5, 'Seven Pounds': 5.0, 'Jaws': 4.5, 'The Wolf Of Wall Street': 5.0, 'Alien': 4.5, 'Whiplash': 5.0, 'Finding Nemo': 5.0, 'Mad Max 2: The Road Warrior': 4.5}}

for i in range(len(similarlisthigh)):
        for key in tempratings[similarlisthigh[i]].keys():  # creates a list of all keys
            if tempratings[similarlisthigh[i]][key] < 3.0: #remove ratings below tolerance
                del tempratings[similarlisthigh[i]][key]
```

This removes all keys from dict `tempratings` that have a corresponding value below 3.0, but leaves identical keys that are 3 or above.

Resulting in (no keys with values below 3.0 now):

```
{'Shane': {'127 Hours': 4.5, 'The Revenant': 4.8, 'Panic Room 4.8': 3.7, 'The Spotlight': 3.6, 'Panic Room': 4.8, 'How I Live Now': 4.6, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 5.0, 'The Martian': 4.8, 'The Hunger Games': 4.5, 'Interstellar': 4.5, 'Dead Poets Society': 5.0, 'The Finest Hours': 4.7}, 'Aaron': {'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.0, 'Pacific Rim': 3.0, 'John Wick': 4.0, 'The Blair Witch Project': 5.0, 'Scott Pilgrim Vs The World': 4.0, 'A Talking Cat': 5.0, 'Space Jam': 5.0}, 'Eli': {'The Guardians Of The Galaxy': 3.5, 'The Breakfast Club': 5.0, 'Back To The Future': 4.0, 'E.T.': 5.0, 'Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome': 3.0, 'Mr. Smith Goes To Washington': 4.7, 'Meet Joe Black': 5.0, 'Jurassic Park': 4.0, 'Pulp Fiction': 4.0, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 5.0, 'The Martian': 4.5, 'Die Hard': 4.0, 'The Dark Knight': 5.0, 'Dead Poets Society': 5.0, 'The Shining': 3.5, 'Inception': 5.0, 'Mad Max': 4.0, '127 Hours': 3.0, 'Rocky': 5.0, 'Blade Runner': 3.5, 'The Wizard Of Oz': 5.0, 'Interstellar': 5.0, 'The Sixth Sense': 3.5, 'Gladiator': 5.0, 'The Lion King': 5.0, 'Toy Story 3': 3.5, 'Good Will Hunting': 5.0, 'The Revenant': 4.5, 'The Matrix': 5.0, 'Full Metal Jacket': 4.5, 'Inglourious Basterds': 5.0, 'Forrest Gump': 5.0, 'Saving Private Ryan': 5.0, 'John Wick': 3.5, 'Up': 3.0, 'Titanic': 5.0, 'Avatar': 5.0, 'Jurassic World': 3.5, 'The Silence Of The Lambs': 4.5, 'Seven Pounds': 5.0, 'Jaws': 4.5, 'The Wolf Of Wall Street': 5.0, 'Alien': 4.5, 'Whiplash': 5.0, 'Finding Nemo': 5.0, 'Mad Max 2: The Road Warrior': 4.5}}
```

What would be the best way to always remove all keys with values below 3.0 *but only* remove other identical keys regardless of value *if* the ratings for the keys that are below 3.0 are above 50%?

For example if Eli rates Titanic 5.0, Jaycee rates it 4.5, Olen rates it 1.0, and Aaron rates it 3.6, it would **not** remove all 'Titanic' keys everywhere, just Olen's because the percentage of the keys with values under 3.0 are under 50%. 25% actually.

But if Eli rates Alien 2.0, Jaycee rates it 4.0, Olen rates it 1.2, and Aaron rates it 2.9, all instances of 'Alien' would be removed as the percentage of ratings under 3.0 is higher than 50%. 75% of ratings are under.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do? Can you give an example of the result you are wishing to achieve please?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Dictionaries (not lists) only have one copy of the key, so if you combine them you'll get the last one merged. Lists might have multiple copies, but lists are written like `[ a,b,c ]` with square brackets.

Comment: The dictionaries have unique keys and so 3rd and the final dictionary is not even possible. Plus please clarify your question. May be take a correct example.

Comment: Really sorry, accidentally posted the wrong question that Stack Overflow saved from last time I never intended to post. Edited to new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to go through twice once to get all the scores and then a second time to average them

```
list_of_dicts = [
  {'127 Hours': 5.0, 'Panic Room': 5.0, 'The Martian': 5.0, 'Revenant': 4.5, 'Avatar': 5.0, 'Nonstop': 4.0},
  {'127 Hours': 5.0, 'Panic Room': 4.0, 'Mad Max': 2.0},
  {'127 Hours': 1.0, 'Panic Room': 2.0, 'Mad Max': 4.0, 'Panic Room': 2.0}     
]
new_data = {}
for data in list_of_dicts:
    for title,score in data.items():
        new_data.setdefault(title,[]).append(score)
def solve_list(scores):
    len_list = len(scores)
    percents = [float(scores.count(x))/len_list for x in scores]
    final_list = [value for value,pct in zip(scores,percents) if pct > 0.3]
    return numpy.average(final_list)
final_dict = dict((k,solve_lists(v)) for k,v in new_data.items())
```

although Im not entirely clear on how you get the scores you listed as expecting... since you are just omitting some of the review scores

Comment: Sorry, accidently posted wrong question when trying to write new one somehow